# Depth First Search tree traversal implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

**Problem Statement:** Say I have n items, weight of each item is listed somewhere. I have to select each combination of the items and find the total weight for each combination (not calculated in the sample code). I want to use DFS to traverse every vertex (each vertex has a unique combination) of the tree.

For example, for 3 items the tree will look like:

```
------------------------------------
        [000]
------------------------------------
        [000]
        /   
    [100]
------------------------------------
        [000]
        /   
    [100]
      /
  [110]
------------------------------------ 
        [000]
        /   
    [100]
      /
  [110]
   /
[111]   
------------------------------------
        [000]
        /   
    [100]
      /  \
  [110]  [101]
   /
[111]
------------------------------------
        [000]
        /  \ 
    [100]  [010]
      /  \
  [110]  [101]
   /       
[111]
------------------------------------
        [000]
        /  \ 
    [100]  [010]
      /  \     \
  [110]  [101] [011]
   /       
[111]
------------------------------------
        [000]----
        /  \     \
    [100]  [010]  [001]
      /  \     \
  [110]  [101] [011]
   /       
[111]
```

Thus there will be 7 combinations of selection given by,
nlist = [item1 item2 item3]
i.e. if item1 and item3 is chosem, nlist is [1 0 1].

I have given the code below. The most important variables are

```
next  --- the next item#
list  --- current selection
nlist --- next selection
```

I expect the following output:

```
#1 ==> next: 1 | list: [000] | nlist: [100]
#2 ==> next: 2 | list: [100] | nlist: [110]
#3 ==> next: 3 | list: [110] | nlist: [111]
#4 ==> next: 3 | list: [100] | nlist: [101]
#5 ==> next: 2 | list: [000] | nlist: [010]
#6 ==> next: 3 | list: [010] | nlist: [011]
#7 ==> next: 3 | list: [000] | nlist: [001]
```

However, I am getting this:

```
#1 ==> next: 1 | list: [000] | nlist: [100]
#2 ==> next: 2 | list: [100] | nlist: [110]
#3 ==> next: 3 | list: [110] | nlist: [111]
#4 ==> next: 3 | list: [111] | nlist: [111] <-- unexpected output begins in this line
#5 ==> next: 2 | list: [111] | nlist: [111]
#6 ==> next: 3 | list: [111] | nlist: [111]
#7 ==> next: 3 | list: [111] | nlist: [111]
```

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

// Declaration of global variables
const int num_IP = 3;
const int num_func = 4;
      int L[num_IP][num_func];
      int Pwr[num_IP];
      int perf[num_func];
      int constraint_matrix[num_func];
      int * p_nlist;
      int iteration;     

int * init_list( ){
  static int list[num_IP];
  for ( int index = 0; index < num_IP; index++ )
    list[index]=0; 
  return list; 
}

int * init_nlist( ){
  static int nlist[num_IP];
  for ( int index = 0; index < num_IP; index++ )
    nlist[index]=0; 
  return nlist;
}

// branch function
int * branch( int * p_list, int next )
{
  cout << '#' << iteration << " ==> " << "next: " << next+1 << " | ";
  cout << "list: [";
  for ( int index = 0; index < num_IP; index++ )
    cout << *(p_list+index);
  cout << "] | ";

  * (p_nlist + next) = 1;

  cout << "nlist: [";
  for ( int index = 0; index < num_IP; index++ )
    cout << *(p_nlist+index);
  cout << "]" << '\n';
  iteration++;

  for ( int i = next+1; i < num_IP; i++ ){
    p_nlist = branch ( p_nlist , i );
  }

  return p_list;
}

////////////////////////////////
// Main Function
////////////////////////////////

int main(){
  // variable declaration and initialization
  int index;   // index variable used for most iterations
  iteration = 1;
  int list[num_IP];
  int nlist[num_IP];
  int * p_list;

  p_list = init_list( );
  p_nlist = init_nlist( );

  // branch implementation  
  for ( int next = 0; next < num_IP; next++ ){
      p_nlist = branch ( p_nlist , next );      
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I have a similar Matlab implementation and that works fine.

The main function in Matlab,

```
% main.m
global num_IP
list = [];
for next=1:num_IP
    [nlist] = branch(list,next);
end
```

and the branch function,

```
% branch.m
function [list] = branch(list,next)

global num_IP

disp('----------------');
next
list
nlist = [list,next]

for i = (next+1):num_IP
    [nlist] = branch(nlist,i);
end
```

Comment: Avoid global variables, mostly when you modify them in recursive function.

Comment: your problem statement is a bit unclear. How does a list of n items constitute a graph? You have stated what are the vertices (the items), but not the edges (the relationship between them)

Comment: This is a C-style implementation, the only C++ thing about this code is usage of `cout`. Why are you not using an appropriate data structure? Use a class that represents a binary tree, this will make you code much easier to understand. As it is, your code is very hard to follow. Also, as Jarod42 pointed out, avoid usage of global variables with recursive function calls.

Comment: Although the approach is stated, the actual problem is a bit unclar. Is there an error message? Does the actual behaviour differ from the expected behaviour?

Comment: BTW, using a `uint` and counting from `0` to `2**3` (`8`) and use bit-mask seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I will refrain from commenting on your program and just point out the bug...

You are setting the elements of an array to `1` with `*(p_nlist + next) = 1`. You never set them back to `0`, so obviously they will never be `0` again once they are set to `1`.

You just need to add 1 line to change the modified element back to 0 after the recursive call:

```
...

for (int i = next + 1; i < num_IP; i++){
    p_nlist = branch(p_nlist, i);
}

*(p_nlist + next) = 0; // ADDED

return p_list;

...
```